# You do not have permission to do this, you got this error because there are no policies allowing this request on this application

Tags: getstream-io

const userToken = client.createUserToken(data.uid);

```
var readToken = client.getReadOnlyToken("user", data.uid);

var readWriteToken = client.getReadWriteToken("user", data.uid);

socket.emit(data.session, {
  token: userToken,
  rwToken: readWriteToken,
  rToken: readToken,
});
```

client side

const user = client.feed('user', this.props.user.uid, data.token);

await user.addActivity({
          actor: client.currentUser,
          verb: 'add',
          object: 'picture:10',
          foreign_id: 'picture:10',
          message: 'Beautiful bird!',
        });

Comment: Probably `this.props.user.uid` isn't different than the id of the user you're generating token for in the backend. Also, your usage (`client.feed`) is deprecated, please see the docs and upgrade.

Comment: assuming this is a dev application, I suggest including here the values for these two vars: this.props.user.uid, data.token